# parallel image processing on hadoop

Tags: image, hadoop, tiles, deepzoom

I have a couple of huge TIFF images (60,000x60,000 ~600MB). Using Hadoop I would like to create a pyramid of tiles (deepzoom format) for each image and store them on HDFS.
Ideally I would like to achieve that each node is processing only the part of the image.

What is the best way to achieve it? 
Will it be a big overhead in storing small files on HDFS?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need hadoop? Your images are not so large. My 6-year-old desktop can make a deepzoom of a larger image in under 4 minutes:

```
$ tiffinfo huge.tif
TIFF Directory at offset 0x12d095e4 (315659748)
  Image Width: 91460 Image Length: 51866
  Tile Width: 512 Tile Length: 512
  Resolution: 10, 10 pixels/cm
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: JPEG
...
$ time vips dzsave huge.tif x
real  3m40.841s
user  4m57.587s
sys   0m50.375s
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will it be a big overhead in storing small files on HDFS?

Check this [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) from Cloudera. With [HDFS federation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.23.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/Federation.html), the problem with large number of files will ease a bit.

http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

> What is the best way to achieve it?

First check if the API for creating deep zoom format can be applied on a part of the image file. If the complete file has to be processed at a time, then there is not much advantage Hadoop is offering. HDFS by default splits the file into 64 MB splits and each split can be processed by a mapper in parallel.

If you are new to Hadoop, see how the basic [word count example](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/mapred_tutorial.html) works in Hadoop and try to do something similar for your requirement.